# Pass array literal to polymer computed binding

Tags: arrays, polymer-1.0

## Effort and Research

I would like to pass an array literal to a computed binding in polymer. My attempt looks like this:

`if="[[ !isMatch(item.Type, ['Inbox', 'Review', 'Invalid']) ]]"`

However, `isMatch` never gets hit. Passing a single string works fine. [The docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#literals) mention string and number literals will work but nothing about arrays.

## Question

Is there a syntax that will allow me to do this, or is the current solution just a series of nested `if`s? Hoping to avoid the latter since it would be less performant.

Comment: Indeed, the docs only mentions strings and numeric literals. To bind an array an easiest option will be to create a readonly property

Comment: Thanks for the point in the right direction. Got it working, and seems much better than nested `if`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion from Tomasz seems like a good option. I added the array in my polymer properties section, then used it in my conditional.

**In Polymer properties**

```
  umoveableCategories: {
    type: Array,
    readOnly: true,
    value: ['Inbox', 'Review', 'Invalid']
  }
```

**The updated conditional**

`if="[[ !isMatch(item.Type, umoveableCategories) ]]"`